# Ubuntu 18.04 can't start nvidia-settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, xorg

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I can't find a way to use the nvidia-settings either via command line or GUI.

When I run `sudo nvidia-settings` I got the following message :

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help`
       for usage information.
```

`ubuntu-drivers devices` produces :

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C8Dsv000017AAsd000039D1bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

The command `prime-select query` outputs :
`nvidia`

First I tried to install the drivers with :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

Then I tried

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

but no changes

I remember that in 16.04 I used a proprietary driver. But now there is no proprietary driver that I can select : 
[software and updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe3a8.png)

Let me know if any additional infos or command output could help to solve the issue.

I also have ukuu (ubuntu kernel update utility) and have the kernel up to date with the last version.